# VS solution with Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4

A team of developers have been working on the same solution for a while. One of developers has created a new project where he added the latest EF. I got latest code from TFS and tried building the solution. while I wasn't getting errors for the new project I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config 133
```

My target's version is 4.0. However when I checked C:\Windows\assembly my EF assemblies are of version 3.5. Is that what causes my problem?

Comment: Yuu have not the same (or newer) version of EF on your system, as is required by the project.

Comment: How would I update to the latest? I checked my nuget package configuration and it showed 6.1.3